# How to add border to list-style?

Tags: html, css

So i have list of items and im using `list-style: decimal;` but i want to add border to only for `li` also for that decimal.
This is my fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zzzpLqwq/  Any suggestion?

Comment: You want a continus border bottm

Comment: yes i want that is going from number to the end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `list-style-position: inside` and the `border` on the `<li>` itself:

```css
ul {
  list-style: decimal;
  display: inline-block;
}
li {
  background: red;
  list-style-position: inside;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>First</li>
  <li>Second</li>
  <li>Thrid</li>
</ul>
```

Your updated [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zzzpLqwq/2/)

Comment: just one qustion... is it possible to make  width for this line? to go just to the end of text?